# How to make acmart stop complaining about missing country in affiliation?

Tags: author, metadata, acmart

Since our paper has many authors, I try to cut down the metadata from the front page of our paper as much as possible. Thereby, I want to go with the name and the university (two lines per author) and take out the email and country parts. However, the missing country field throws an error. Is there a way to suppress this error?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As the automatic comment suggests: please add the minimal but complete code of a document that, when compiled, demonstrates this issue. That helps in reproducing the problem and makes suggestion solutions easier and faster.

Comment: The error originates from the acmart class that mandates using the country metadata in the affiliation section starting with v1.75 (https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart). Thereby, it has nothing to do with my coding. I am instead looking for a way to avoid this, as our conference chairs are fine with omitting that field.

Comment: I understand that it is not your code that is causing the problem. However, it would still be helpful if you provide a minimal document. In this case that is very simple, just the documentclass, author information, begin/end document, maketitle. People that want to answer could do that themselves, but they shouldn't have to - it takes time from the answerers and you can help them spend their time more efficiently by providing the example yourself (after all it is your question, and the answerers are all volunteers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the installation and user's guide

> The fields `\institution`, `\city` and `\country` are mandatory. If
> they are not provided, an error or a warning is issued. Currently the
> absence of `\country` produces and error; ACM may change this in the
> future.

I suggest downgrading the error to a warning. This will finish the compilation with the warnings in the log file.

Add this code after `\documentclass[options]{acmart}` in your document.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@ACM@checkaffil{% Only warnings
    \if@ACM@instpresent\else
    \ClassWarningNoLine{\@classname}{No institution present for an affiliation}%
    \fi
    \if@ACM@citypresent\else
    \ClassWarningNoLine{\@classname}{No city present for an affiliation}%
    \fi
    \if@ACM@countrypresent\else
        \ClassWarningNoLine{\@classname}{No country present for an affiliation}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This code allows you to test the functionality.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

\makeatletter
\def\@ACM@checkaffil{% Only warnings <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \if@ACM@instpresent\else
    \ClassWarningNoLine{\@classname}{No institution present for an affiliation}%
    \fi
    \if@ACM@citypresent\else
    \ClassWarningNoLine{\@classname}{No city present for an affiliation}%
    \fi
    \if@ACM@countrypresent\else
        \ClassWarningNoLine{\@classname}{No country present for an affiliation}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}

\acmJournal{JACM}
\acmVolume{37}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{111}
\acmMonth{8}

\begin{document}

\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}

%%% used to denote shared contribution to the research.
\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
%  \country{USA} 
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\author{Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}
  \streetaddress{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}
  \city{Hekla}
%  \country{Iceland}
}
\email{larst@affiliation.org}


\begin{abstract}
  A clear and well-documented \LaTeX\ document is presented as an
  article formatted for publication by ACM in a conference proceedings
  or journal publication. Based on the ``acmart'' document class, this
  article presents and explains many of the common variations, as well
  as many of the formatting elements an author may use in the
  preparation of the documentation of their work.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
ACM's consolidated article template, introduced in 2017, provides a
consistent \LaTeX\ style for use across ACM publications, and
incorporates accessibility and metadata-extraction functionality
necessary for future Digital Library endeavors. Numerous ACM and
SIG-specific \LaTeX\ templates have been examined, and their unique
features incorporated into this single new template.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mentioned, "Add this code after \documentclass{...", where is that source file exactly in which I am supposed to add that snippet?

Comment: @Ninja Bug In your document. See the example at the end of my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to add `\country{}` in the affiliation but keep the body empty (if you don't want to add the country). Here is how the affiliation would look like in this case.

```
\affiliation{
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \country{} 
}
```